# I'm not managing to prove that, $\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm not managing to prove that, $$\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$$I think it should be used something like domestic product, but do not know how to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2\le\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\iff\frac1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2\le\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\iff$$

$$\iff\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n 1^2\cdot\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$$

and now apply directly [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

Answer (score 2):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$(a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n})(1+1+\cdots+1)\ge (a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n})^2$$